# How to read developer.android.com documentation?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, documentation

I searched for tutorials how to read developer.android.com documentation but didn't find any. Now I want to use function `setOnCheckedChangeListener` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) . As I see, I need to `import android.widget.CompoundButton` class, so I did this but when I typed `setOnCeckedChangeListener`, it still shows me `Unresolved reference: setOnCheckedChangeListener` I just want to figure out how to read documenation to learn easier. What I'm doing wrong here? This is my code I'm trying to use in onCreate():

```
button.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }
```

Edited:

```
package com.example.stack

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.widget.CompoundButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "What I'm doing wrong here?" -- we cannot answer that, as we cannot see what is in your editor. You might want to edit your question and post your entire Kotlin file, then point out where you are trying to type `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and are running into the error.

Comment: Thanks for comment, you can look at my entire Kotlin file. See "Edited:".

Comment: Presumably, `button` is not a `CompoundButton`, such as a `CheckBox` or `Switch`. That would be in your `activity_main` layout resource.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks. I didn't read all things about it.